# elasticsearch sum more then 10000 results

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to know how to do a sum aggregation with more than 10000 results plz ?

I can't find it in the docs

Thank you.

```
    GET index/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "2022-01-01 00:00",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "nb_sms": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "sms_count"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do partitions and then sum the results of the partitions.
you can check this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions

It is going to split you data not evenly but it is not going to duplicate anything.
So, you can do aggregation for the partitions and a bucket_sum of that aggregation, and a subaggregation under the partition for the sum.